# How to change onclick attribute of a HTML Label in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onclick, htmlcontrols

ok, i have this:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">  
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checks" value="1">
    <label for="check1">1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checks" value="2">
    <label for="check2">2</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="checks" value="3">
    <label for="check3">3</label>
</div>
```

and i'm looking for a way to set the *"onclick"* attribute of those labels with **ASP.NET VB Codebehind**, making the labels looks like:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">  
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checks" value="1">
    <label for="check1" onclick="some javascript">1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checks" value="2">
    <label for="check2" onclick="some javascript">2</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="checks" value="3">
    <label for="check3" onclick="some javascript">3</label>
</div>
```

so, is that possible?

Comment: why do you need the onClick as codebehind ? you can use jQuery instead.

Comment: is nothing special i just want to add some behavior when the user click the label, but these **checkbox** are the HTML output code from a CheckBoxList, and i can't set the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `asp:Label`.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblChk1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="check1" Text="1">
</asp:Label>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
lblChk1.Attributes.Add("onclick","some javascript");
```

Edit: You could simply use `asp:CheckBox` and use its `Text` Property. Clicking the text would then fire the onclick event of your `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ID` attribute and add `runat=server` for your labels. Then you can access the labels from your code-behind:

```
<div class="radio-toolbar">  
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checks" value="1">
    <label ID="label1" runat="server" for="check1">1</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checks" value="2">
    <label ID="label2" runat="server" for="check2">2</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="checks" value="3">
    <label ID="label2" runat="server" for="check3">3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is i can't set the id, these checkboxes are the HTML output code from a CheckBoxList

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a html label i would use the ASP.NET `Label` control with [`AssociatedControlID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx) attribute which is rendered as `label for`.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" 
   AssociatedControlID="check1" 
   onclick="somejavascript" 
   runat="server" 
   Text="1"></asp:Label>
```

You can also add the javascript from codebehind:

```
Label1.Attributes.Add("onclick","somejavascript");
```

From MSDN:

> ...
>   **When the AssociatedControlID property is set, the Label control
>   renders as an HTML label element, with the for attribute set to the ID
>   property of the associated control.** You can set other attributes of
>   the label element using the Label properties. For example, you can use
>   the Text and AccessKey properties to provide the caption and hot key
>   for an associated control.

`